# Where should I check if username already exist in rest api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I am creating a rest application using Spring Boot. I've got three logical layers: controller, service, and repository. Where should I check if the given username and similar values already exist in the database?

In the controller layer, I check user input (length, size, etc.) Can I also check username existence here? For instance:

```
if(this.userService.existUserByUsername(request.getUsername()))
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
                HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "User with given username already exists");
```

Can I check it in the service layer by invoking the registry method (existByUsername) and throwing a custom error, then caught in the controller?

```
public void addUser(SignUpRequestDto signUpRequestDto){
    
    if(this.userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequestDto.getUsername()))
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("User with given uusernamealready exist");
    else
        this.userRepository.save(this.convertSignUpRequestDtoToEntity(signUpRequestDto));
}
```

Or maybe I should rely on hibernate annotations on entities and handle these exceptions?

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "username", unique = true)
private String username;
```

I really appreciate all feedback from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I check if the given username and similar values already exist in the database?

Probably in the same logical layer that the rest of your business logic lives.  Service layer?

> In the controller layer, I check user input (length, size, etc.) Can I also check username existence here?

You can, of course.  It's probably not a good idea; parsing inputs to make sure that they conform to a schema that you understand is a boundary concern.  Using the inputs that you understand is a domain concern.

> Can I check it in the service layer by invoking the registry method (existByUsername) and throwing a custom error, then caught in the controller?

You can - you may get some push back during code review about whether an *exception* is the right implementation mechanism to handle that.  There are alternative approaches, and trade offs between them, and contexts (throwing exceptions within a layer vs throwing exceptions between layers).

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for your opinion :)